# Generate the history tables automatically when CRUD operation performs on entity in jhipster generated application

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jhipster

Generate the history/audit tables for each entity  when performing CRUD operation on entity.

How to maintain the history of the all the columns each entity?

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried the entity audit module ? See  https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-entity-audit

Comment: we  are using generator-jhipster-entity-audit and it will includethe.Base abstract class for entities which will hold definitions for created, last modified by and created,
 * last modified by date.My  question how to maintain the history of the all the columns each entity

Comment: JHipster does not provide it out of the box but there's nothing specific to JHipster here so you can implement it using standard JPA/Hibernate, have you looked at the `@RevisionEntity`annotation from Hibernate ?

Comment: Model entity data storing as lobid in in jhi_entity_audit_event table .So  fetching  the history of the model by passing event_id.event_id is model id.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/producers/history/{id}")
    public List<Producer> getProducerHistory(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a history of Producers");
        List<EntityAuditEvent> result = producerService.findByEntityId(id);
        List<Producer> producerHistoryList = null;
        if (result != null && result.size() > 0) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
            producerHistoryList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (EntityAuditEvent data : result) {
                try {
                    Producer producer = objectMapper.readValue(data.getEntityValue(), Producer.class);
                    producerHistoryList.add(producer);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return producerHistoryList;
    }

@Override
    public List<EntityAuditEvent> findByEntityId(Long id) {
         List<EntityAuditEvent> listEvents= this.entityAuditEventRepository.findByEntityIdOrderByModifiedDateDesc(id);
        return listEvents;
    }
```